# How to use sudo inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, sudo, linux-containers

Normally, docker containers are run using the user **root**. I'd like to use a different user, which is no problem using docker's USER directive. But this user should be able to use **sudo** inside the container. This command is missing.

Here's a simple Dockerfile for this purpose:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

RUN useradd docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd
RUN mkdir -p /home/docker && chown -R docker:docker /home/docker

USER docker
CMD /bin/bash
```

Running this container, I get logged in with user 'docker'. When I try to use sudo, the command isn't found. So I tried to install the *sudo* package inside my Dockerfile using

```
RUN apt-get install sudo
```

This results in *Unable to locate package sudo*

Comment: Just give sudo group to user. http://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line

Answer (score 384, accepted):

Just got it. As regan pointed out, I had to add the user to the sudoers group. But the main reason was I'd forgotten to update the repositories cache, so apt-get couldn't find the sudo package. It's working now. Here's the completed code:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get -y install sudo

RUN useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && adduser docker sudo

USER docker
CMD /bin/bash
```

Comment: doesn't work in centos.  the `adduser` command spits out the usage help for `useradd`

Comment: For CentOS, you could add a user and group, then create a shard file under `/etc/sudoers.d/` and set the permissions to `440` on that file. Then the user would have sudo access under CentOS, 6 and up. 5 you'll have to add the `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` directive in `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have those errors:
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working for Ubuntu 18.04 docker image

Comment: My user is called `bot`. Is the right adaptation of your commands: ` RUN useradd -m bot
RUN echo "bot:bot" | chpasswd
RUN && adduser docker sudo` maybe explaining `echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && adduser docker sudo` would have helped.

Comment: Does not work. `sudo: a terminal is required to read the password`

Comment: `adduser` creates a new user. To add the `docker` user to the `sudo` group, use `usermod -a -G sudo docker`.

Comment: add what user to sudoers ? what user runs the docker "RUN" commands?

Answer (score 408):

When neither `sudo` nor `apt-get` is available in the container, you can also jump into running container as `root` user using command:

```
docker exec -u root -t -i container_id /bin/bash
```

Comment: This is a much better solution to what the OP probably wants to achieve, even though the accepted answer gives the requested solution. At the very least, it's the answer I was looking for!

Comment: This is the best answer, instead of doing it the hard way with the dockerfile.

Comment: +1 I had an issue in changing permission inside docker.. Came to know that only root user can perform this action and this is the only way to accomplish it.  In this way, no sudo is required for me!

Comment: Somebody give this man a medal

Comment: In case you can not use /bin/bash then use /bin/sh instead.
'docker exec -u root -t -i container_id /bin/sh'

Comment: this looks nice but when I get into my container nothing seems to have ebeen installed? `docker pull  brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test` then `docker run -u root -ti brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test_arm bash`. Why? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73735508/why-is-my-container-when-starting-as-root-seem-to-be-empty

Comment: This didn't work for me. This did: `docker exec -u 0 -it container_id bash`

Comment: Best answer for sure!

Answer (score 150):

The other answers didn't work for me. I kept searching and found a [blog post](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/08/29/docker-non-root.html) that covered how a team was running non-root inside of a docker container.

Here's the TL;DR version:

```
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y sudo

RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' docker
RUN adduser docker sudo
RUN echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

USER docker

# this is where I was running into problems with the other approaches
RUN sudo apt-get update
```

I was using `FROM node:9.3` for this, but I suspect that other similar container bases would work as well.

Comment: I am using `ubuntu:bionic-20180724.1`. I used this approach but, after the above, it does not allow me to install another package. I appended one line to the above `Dockerfile` in order to install a package with: `RUN apt-get install -y tree`. However, it gave me this error message: `Step xxxx/xxxx : RUN apt-get install -y tree
 ---> Running in j5e6gsvwfafa
Reading package lists...
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/`

Comment: @WR I think you need to change that line to read `RUN sudo apt-get install -y tree`. After setting the `USER` to something other than `root`, you'll need to use `sudo` for any commands that require `root` privileges.

Answer (score 90):

For anyone who has this issue with an already running container, and they don't necessarily want to rebuild, the following command connects to a running container with root privileges:

```
docker exec -ti -u root container_name bash
```

You can also connect using its ID, rather than its name, by finding it with:

```
docker ps -l
```

To save your changes so that they are still there when you next launch the container (or docker-compose cluster) - note that these changes would not be repeated if you rebuild from scratch:

```
docker commit container_id image_name
```

To roll back to a previous image version (warning: this deletes history rather than appends to the end, so to keep a reference to the current image, tag it first using the optional step):

```
docker history image_name
docker tag latest_image_id my_descriptive_tag_name  # optional
docker tag desired_history_image_id image_name
```

To start a container that isn't running and connect as root:

```
docker run -ti -u root --entrypoint=/bin/bash image_id_or_name -s
```

To copy from a running container:

```
docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target
```

To export a copy of the image:

```
docker save container | gzip > /dir/file.tar.gz
```

Which you can restore to another Docker install using:

```
gzcat /dir/file.tar.gz | docker load
```

It is much quicker but takes more space to not compress, using:

```
docker save container | dir/file.tar
```

And:

```
cat dir/file.tar | docker load
```

Comment: Using `docker exec` and `docker commit` to create a new image is not an especially maintainable path; if you need to recreate the image for any reason (say there's a security issue in the original base image) these manual steps won't be tracked anywhere.

Comment: Are you saying it would be better to put the commands in the `Dockerfile` or `entrypoint` and rebuild? I might be misunderstanding your point, I do start with 'For anyone who has this issue with an already running container, and they don't necessarily want to rebuild', and I specifically warn the moment we can't backtrack. I have added your warning 'these changes would not be repeated if you rebuild from scratch'. Is there anything else you would add?

Answer (score 24):

if you want to connect to container and install something 
using apt-get 
first as above answer from our brother "Tomáš Záluský"

```
docker exec -u root -t -i container_id /bin/bash
```

then try to

> RUN apt-get update or apt-get 'anything you want'

it worked with me 
hope it's useful for all

Answer (score 15):

Unlike [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25908200/1074998), I use `usermod` instead.

Assume already logged-in as root in docker, and "fruit" is the new non-root username I want to add, simply run this commands:

```
apt update && apt install sudo
adduser fruit
usermod -aG sudo fruit
```

Remember to save image after update. Use `docker ps` to get current running docker's <CONTAINER ID> and <IMAGE>, then run `docker commit -m "added sudo user" <CONTAINER ID>  <IMAGE>` to save docker image.

Then test with:

```
su fruit
sudo whoami
```

Or test by direct login(ensure save image first) as that non-root user when launch docker:

```
docker run -it --user fruit <IMAGE>
sudo whoami
```

You can use `sudo -k` to reset password prompt timestamp:

```
sudo whoami # No password prompt
sudo -k # Invalidates the user's cached credentials
sudo whoami # This will prompt for password
```

Answer (score 12):

If **SUDO** or **apt-get** is not accessible inside the Container, You can use, below option in running container.

```
docker exec -u root -it f83b5c5bf413 ash
```

"**f83b5c5bf413"  is my container ID** & here is working example from my terminal:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Here's how I setup a non-root user with the base image of `ubuntu:18.04`:

```
RUN \
    groupadd -g 999 foo && useradd -u 999 -g foo -G sudo -m -s /bin/bash foo && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^%sudo.*/%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^root.*/root ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^#includedir.*/## **Removed the include directive** ##"/g' && \
    echo "foo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && \
    echo "Customized the sudoers file for passwordless access to the foo user!" && \
    echo "foo user:";  su - foo -c id
```

What happens with the above code:

- The user and group `foo` is created.
- The user `foo` is added to the both the `foo` and `sudo` group.
- The `uid` and `gid` is set to the value of `999`.
- The home directory is set to `/home/foo`.
- The shell is set to `/bin/bash`.
- The `sed` command does inline updates to the `/etc/sudoers` file to allow `foo` and `root` users passwordless access to the `sudo` group.
- The `sed` command disables the `#includedir` directive that would allow any files in subdirectories to override these inline updates.

Answer (score 7):

This may not work for all images, but some images contain a root user already, such as in the jupyterhub/singleuser image.  With that image it's simply:

```
USER root
RUN sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: for the image "fabric8/java-centos-openjdk8-jdk" just adding USER root before the RUN command solved my problem, didn't even need to add the sudo

Answer (score 7):

The main idea is that you need to create user that is a root user according to the container.

Main commands:

```
RUN echo "bot:bot" | chpasswd
RUN adduser bot sudo
```

the first sends the literal string `bot:bot` to `chpasswd` which creates the user bot with the password `bot`, chpasswd does:

```
The chpasswd command reads a list of user name and password pairs from standard input and uses this information to update a group of existing users. Each line is of the format:

user_name:password

By default the supplied password must be in clear-text, and is encrypted by chpasswd. Also the password age will be updated, if present.
```

The second command I assume adds the user bot as sudo.

Full docker container to play with:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
# FROM --platform=linux/amd64 continuumio/miniconda3

MAINTAINER Brando Miranda "me@gmail.com"

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ssh \
    git \
    m4 \
    libgmp-dev \
    opam \
    wget \
    ca-certificates \
    rsync \
    strace \
    gcc \
    rlwrap \
    sudo

# https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/pull/2103

RUN useradd -m bot
# format for chpasswd user_name:password
RUN echo "bot:bot" | chpasswd
RUN adduser bot sudo

WORKDIR /home/bot
USER bot
#CMD /bin/bash
```

Comment: i get  the follwoing error when running the dockerfile   :  /bin/sh: useradd: not found . No idea why

Answer (score 2):

If you have a container running as root that runs a script (which you can't change) that needs access to the `sudo` command, you can simply create a new `sudo` script in your `$PATH` that calls the passed command.

e.g. In your Dockerfile:

```
RUN if type sudo 2>/dev/null; then \ 
     echo "The sudo command already exists... Skipping."; \
    else \
     echo -e "#!/bin/sh\n\${@}" > /usr/sbin/sudo; \
     chmod +x /usr/sbin/sudo; \
    fi
```

Comment: Depending on the docker images you are using (in my case Ubuntu:18.04), you might need to remove the `-e` from the `echo`. Otherwise it will be present in the file itself, rendering it infunctional.

Comment: Neat idea, but this will not work if the original command is using sudo options, such as `sudo -E ls`. It will try to execute `-E ls`.

Answer (score 2):

An example Dockerfile for Centos7. In this example we add prod_user with privilege of sudo.

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y update && yum clean all

RUN yum -y install openssh-server  python3 sudo

RUN adduser -m prod_user && \
    echo "MyPass*49?" | passwd prod_user --stdin && \
    usermod -aG wheel prod_user && \
    mkdir /home/prod_user/.ssh && \
    chown prod_user:prod_user -R  /home/prod_user/ && \
    chmod 700 /home/prod_user/.ssh

RUN echo "prod_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && \
    echo "%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

RUN echo "PasswordAuthentication yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config

RUN systemctl enable sshd.service

VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer on how to do this on CentOS.
On Centos, you can add following to Dockerfile

```
RUN echo "user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/user && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/user
```

Comment: But this command still failed:
```bash
Step 6/8 : RUN echo "user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/user && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/user
 ---> Running in daea0aae031c
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /etc/sudoers.d/user: Permission denied
```

Comment: This essentially makes your "non-root" user equivalent to root, so long as an attacker knows to preface their commands with `sudo`.  It's very marginally better than running as root, but not something I'd generally recommend in a Docker setup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an Ubuntu image, while using the docker desktop had faced this issue.

The following resolved the issue:

1. apt-get update
2. apt-get install sudo