# Not able to deploy Python program from Azure IOT Edge to Rasberry Pi

Tags: docker, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I installed the IOT Edge runtime using below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-linux-arm

I am following the below tutorial to deploy a docker image to IOT Edge (Rasberry Pi):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart-linux 
and able to deploy the tempSensor image to my Rasberry Pi

I decided to deploy my own program "blink.py". 

I created the program and its working fine in the local Rasberry Pi using below command:

```
$docker container run --device /dev/gpiomem -d blink
```

I followed the below steps to deploy my own program from Azure IOT Edge portal:

1.) Create a docker image using Dockerfile:

```
FROM arm32v7/python:2.7.15-stretch
COPY blink.py
CMD ["python","./blink.py"]
```

then ran the command:

```
$docker build -t "blink" ./
```

2.) Now i pushed the image to Azure container Registry. Followed below steps:

a.) Login to Azure container registry

```
$docker login blink.azurecr.io
```

b.) Push to Azure container registry

```
$docker tag blink link.azurecr.io/blink
$docker push blink.azurecr.io/blink
```

3.) Deploy image in Azure container registry to IOT Edge device using below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart-linux#deploy-a-module

I see a container image created in the Raspberry Pi as "blink.azurecr.io/blink"

I see that IOTEdge runtime tried to deploy this image as container but it failed.

When i try to see the logs using command

```
>docker logs blink
```

It shows an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./blink.py", line 6, in <module>
    GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.OUT) 
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root!
```

Seems like some access issue but not sure how to solve it?
Do i need to put anything in the createOptions while deploying the edge module from azure portal ?

-Sandy

Answer (score 0):

From the error log, it seems that the module has no permission to access device/gpio. **sudo** should be able to used inside the container. You can try to add the following command in Dockerfile.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install sudo

RUN useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && adduser docker sudo
```

This [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845538/how-to-use-sudo-inside-a-docker-container) in stackoverflow as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

ok so it worked!
I provided below in the createOptions:

```
{
    "HostConfig": {
        "Devices": [
            {
                "PathOnHost": "/dev/gpiomem",
                "PathInContainer": "/dev/gpiomem",
                "CgroupPermissions": "rwm"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

After re-deploying.. it worked, Hurray !!!!