# How to reset admin password in openproject dockerized

Tags: docker, openproject

I installed openproject in CentOS 7 using docker.
I changed the admin password and then I forgot it.

How can I reset it.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For newer versions of OpenProject, [Ulferts' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55137192/1116842) seems not to work, but I was successfull using the information in [this guide](https://community.openproject.com/topics/1043):

1. Find out the container ID: `docker ps`.
2. Connect to the docker container as root: `docker exec -u root -it <CONTAINER ID> /bin/bash`
3. Change the users password with rails console:

   ```sh
   RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c
   u = User.find_by_login "admin"
   u.password=u.password_confirmation='my new password'
   u.save
   ```
4. (Hit Ctrl-D until you're back on your regular terminal.)

Comment: If you have OpenProject installation in 6, do it in the container running 'web' service.

Answer (score 5):

If the settings permit (which is the default), the easiest solution would be to go to the login page (`https://[host]/login`) of the OpenProject installation (via a browser) and use the "Forgot your password?" link to have a password reset token send to the email address configured for the admin account.

If that option does not exist, you have to connect to the docker container to get a terminal window on it, e.g. by following this [how-to](http://phase2.github.io/devtools/common-tasks/ssh-into-a-container/).

Once you have a bash open, issue:

```
sudo openproject run rails console
```

which will open a rails console for you.

Once inside, issue:

```rb
# retrieve first admin account
admin = User.where(admin: true).first
# change the password
admin.password = admin.password_confirmation = "[The password you choose]"
# Save the change disregarding any errors
admin.save(validate: false)
```

In case you have more than one admin account on the installation, you will have to narrow down the correct one in the first step by e.g.

```rb
# print a list of all admin accounts
pp User.where(admin: true).pluck(:id, :login, :firstname, :lastname, :mail)
# Fetch admin account by id
admin = User.where(id: "[the id]")
```

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to use your solution but I get errors:


root@ee12ce60a11b:/app# sudo openproject run rails console
bash: sudo: command not found
root@ee12ce60a11b:/app# openproject run rails console
bash: openproject: command not found
```

Comment: I'd assume that sudo ist not installed. You might fix the problem by connecting to the docker container as root: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49529946/3206935

Comment: I connected as root, but: `/app# openproject run rails console` results in `bash: openproject: command not found`

Comment: I used  ` admin = User.where(admin: true, login: "admin"  ).first `  to change the password of the specific admin.