# /bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found when running dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This is the content of my Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN sudo apt-get update

RUN sudo apt-get install -y wget

CMD wget -O- -q http://ifconfig.me/ip
```

When I run the Dockerfile to build a docker image, I get the below error:

> /bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found

Can you please help me in solving the above error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use sudo inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845538/how-to-use-sudo-inside-a-docker-container)

Comment: $ docker run -it ubuntu  then inside container # su

Comment: remove sudo from Dockerfile

Comment: After removing SUDO from dockerfile, i am getting a new error E: Unable to locate package wget

Comment: @yeputons I would not say it is a duplicate of [How to use sudo inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845538/how-to-use-sudo-inside-a-docker-container) since it does not mention the error message, and the answer to this question here is already the first sentence in the question there.

Comment: for large Dockerfile files, make sure the `USER` variable isn't being assigned/changed. This will make all further commands run as that user and not root.

Answer (score 54):

by default docker container runs as ***root*** user
**remove** the **sudo** from **Dockerfile** and run again.

[image]

Comment: also prompt with # signifies root user

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket  

this should help you for Docker Daemon permission related

Answer (score 13):

Your commands in the Dockerfile already run as `root` during `docker build`. For this reason you do not need to use `sudo`

Answer (score 7):

You don't need sudo in this case. Change Dockerfile as below -

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update -y && \ 
    apt-get install -y wget

CMD wget -O- -q http://ifconfig.me/ip
```

PS - Merge the RUN statements as much as possible.