# How do I become root in a docker container

Tags: docker

I run this command on my local machine 
docker run -d --name SonarQube -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 sonarqube

This takes the image of the branch from dockerhub and then creates a container of the image.Now I want to make some changes in the file but there is no editor in the container.I tried installing vi using apt-get but it says I need to be the root user to execute the command and when I write sudo it says command not found.How do I install the editor in the container?

I run this command to install vim
sudo apt-get install vim

And this is the error which I get

bash: sudo: command not found

Comment: please share exact command and error

Comment: Just mount over the file you want to change.

Comment: As Joe asked, what file are you trying to change? Typically with a docker container you do not want to make changes to the image directly.

Comment: I want to make changes in the config file

Comment: you must be already a root user inside the container, unless a user is created and specified specifically

Comment: Considering containers are immutable, changing their configuration interactively (and within the container) isn't the best idea. See Option 2 in the advanced configuration section of [sonarqube's image description](https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Sonorqube Docker info at https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube/ the config files are in bind mounted persistent volumes. You can change the configs in a local directory

> The images contain the SonarQube installation at /opt/sonarqube. You
>   can use bind-mounted persistent volumes to override selected files or
>   directories, for example:
>
> sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf: configuration files, such as
>   sonar.properties

or you can specify them on the command line

```
> $ docker run -d --name sonarqube \  
>     -p 9000:9000 \  
>     -v /path/to/conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf \  
>     -v /path/to/data:/opt/sonarqube/data \  
>     -v /path/to/logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs \  
>     -v /path/to/extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions \  
>     sonarqube
```

You should try not to edit files directly in a Docker container. If you really need to get the file in a running container, try editing the file locally and Docker cp it into the container

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-

If you still really want to sudo in the container, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845538/how-to-use-sudo-inside-a-docker-container) post, it might help.

Answer (score 3):

Try to pass user to docker run command.

```
docker run -it --user root --name SonarQube -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 sonarqube
```

But you might see same issue with this approach as this will start the container with `root`, not [sonarqube](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/c2ec0708e5c20c4bed02606c3b626dede5e3b8a7/7/community/Dockerfile) user.

So I will recommend to go  with the below approach.

```
FROM sonarqube
USER root
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y vim
USER sonarqube
ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/run.sh"]
```

**USER**

> root (id = 0) is the default user within a container. The image
>   developer can create additional users. Those users are accessible by
>   name. When passing a numeric ID, the user does not have to exist in
>   the container.
>
> The developer can set a default user to run the first process with the
>   Dockerfile USER instruction. When starting a container, the operator
>   can override the USER instruction by passing the -u option.

```
-u="", --user="": Sets the username or UID used and optionally the groupname or GID for the specified command.

The followings examples are all valid:
--user=[ user | user:group | uid | uid:gid | user:gid | uid:group ]
```

[reference-run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

Answer (score 0):

You can run below command for running container as root:

```
docker exec --user root -it <CONT-NAME> /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run with cont-name command for running container as root:

```
#docker exec --user root -it containername /bin/bash
```