# How to run an sh script in docker file?

Tags: docker, sh

When running a sh script in docker file, i got the following error:

> ./upload.sh: 5: ./upload.sh: sudo: not found ./upload.sh: 21:
>   ./upload.sh: Bad substitution

```
sudo chmod 755 upload.sh # line 5
version=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
echo "version $version"
echo "Uploading file"

for path in $(find public/files -name "*.txt"); do
  echo "path $path"
  WORDTOREMOVE="public/" 
  echo "WORDTOREMOVE $WORDTOREMOVE"
  # cause of the error
  newpath=${path//$WORDTOREMOVE/} # Line 21
  echo "new path $path"
  url=http://localhost:3000/${newpath}
  ...
  echo "Uploading file"
  ...
done
```

DockerFile

```
FROM node:10-slim

EXPOSE 3000 4001


WORKDIR /prod/code
...
COPY . .

RUN ./upload.sh
RUN npm run build
CMD ./DockerRun.sh
```

Any idea?

Comment: Where are you deploying your container?

Comment: This should help `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845538/how-to-use-sudo-inside-a-docker-container`

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean exactly, but i try to build docker image locally
docker build -t myApp .

Comment: if sudo is not found, you probably need to install it in the container

Comment: You are using a `bash` extension (`${path//...}`) but trying to run the script using `/bin/sh`.

Comment: You also probably don't need `sudo` at all – things in a Dockerfile usually run as root unless you explicitly pick a different `USER`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone faces the same issue, here how I fixed it

1. `chmod +x upload.sh`
2. `git update-index --chmod=+x upload.sh` (mandatory if you pushed the file to remote branch before changing its permission)

Answer (score 1):

The docker image you are using (node:10-slim) has no sudo installed on it because this docker image runs processes as user root:

`docker run -it node:10-slim bash
root@68dcffceb88c:/# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
root@68dcffceb88c:/# which sudo
root@68dcffceb88c:/#`

When your Dockerfile runs `RUN ./upload.sh` it will run:
`sudo chmod 755 upload.sh`

Using sudo inside the docker fails because sudo is not installed, there is no need to use sudo inside the docker because all of the commands inside the docker run as user root.

Simply remove the sudo from line number 5.

If you wish to update the running PATH variable run:

`PATH=$PATH:/directorytoadd/bin`

This will append the directory "/directorytoadd/bin" to the current path.

Comment: actually i want to remove WORDTOREMOVE from path (remove substring from string)