# How ro run sudo su - in Dockerfile

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dock

I am trying to `RUN` `sudo su -` inside the Dockerfile and I get this error

> /bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found

This is how my `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN sudo su - 
RUN apt update && install openjdk-8-jdk
RUN wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add - && sudo sh -c  'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kenkins.list'
RUN apt update && apt install jenkins

RUN curl -fsSL get.docker.com | /bin/bash
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins && systemctl restart jenkins
```

This error comes when I try to build it.
`docker build -t jenkins .`
Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you try doing apt update? I believe you're already running those commands as root and therefor there's no need for sudo.

Comment: So no need of running `sudo su -` ?

Comment: Any reason to do that? This command seems not to be doing anything except for creating an extra layer without any useful effect.

Comment: Yeah, unless your jenkins user needs sudo. You can check what user you're runni g those commands with the 'who' command.
As in: RUN who

If your jenkins user needs sudo, look into this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25908200

Comment: BTW, using systemctl is not recommend, the best practices tell that you will be better with a starting script that boots the inner server, instead of using a control service.

Comment: @Victor can you provide an example?

Comment: Look for /etc/init.d/

Answer (score 2):

The dockerfile will run as a virtual "root" user by default, so there is no need to include any sudo command.

Since the example script contains no "-y" defaults it seems that you have simply typed the description for a manual installation into a script. This will never work. And well, in a container the application does also need to be on PID-1 which systemctl will not do.

After going through a basic tutorial on docker you will find out why.

Answer (score 1):

This command seems not to be doing anything except for creating an extra layer without any useful effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat Dockerfile

FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y
```

If You want to change the use privilege use **USER** flag in Dockerfile