# Add sudo permission (without password ) to user by command line

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, sudo, sudoers

I'm creating a docker file from ubuntu:bionic image.

I want an ubuntu user with sudo privileges.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Get the basic stuff
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y \
    sudo

# Create ubuntu user with sudo privileges
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash ubuntu && \
    usermod -aG sudo ubuntu

# Set as default user
USER ubuntu
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND teletype

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

But with this aproach I need to write the password of ubuntu user.

There is a way to add NOPASSWD clausule to sudo group in sudoers file by command line?

Comment: You shouldn't ever need `sudo` in Docker: a container only runs one process, and when you launch it you can explicitly specify the user at the `docker run` command line (or, if you need a debugging shell, `docker exec -u` can launch it as an alternate user).  What's the application you're trying to package, and how does it need `sudo`?  Does [How to use sudo inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845538/how-to-use-sudo-inside-a-docker-container) have enough information for you?

Comment: You are rigth. But itis not my call.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, you are not suggested to use `sudo` in docker. You could well design your behavior using `USER` + `gosu`.

**But**, if you insist for some uncontrolled reason, just add next line after you setup normal user:

```
RUN echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
```

So for your scenario, the workable one is:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Get the basic stuff
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y \
    sudo

# Create ubuntu user with sudo privileges
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash ubuntu && \
    usermod -aG sudo ubuntu
# New added for disable sudo password
RUN echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

# Set as default user
USER ubuntu
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND teletype

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

**Test the effect:**

```
$ docker build -t abc:1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/9 : FROM ubuntu:bionic
......
Successfully built b3aa0793765f
Successfully tagged abc:1

$ docker run --rm abc:1 cat /etc/sudoers
cat: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied

$ docker run --rm abc:1 sudo cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
......
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

You could see with `sudo`, we could already execute a root-needed command.